# Why doesn't .slideDown( ) work with this If/Else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/4SbXV/

It worked fine before adding the if/else statement so I'm a little confused on what happen.  I'm just trying to get it to just fade out and fade in the new content when it is clicked if the #projectpanel is displayed.. any ideas on why this isnt working?

Also having problems with the close button if any1 can point out what I'm doing wrong with that since its not doing anything at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closebutton does not work because the class names do not match, and you need to add `live()`

`$("#projectpanel").slideUp(500).hide;`

is missing:

`$("#projectpanel").slideUp(500).hide();`

http://jsfiddle.net/4SbXV/8/

Edit: fiddle updated

Comment: He's using jQuery l.7.1 in his JS Fiddle; therefore [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated (and also very poorly implemented), [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is now recommended for 1.7+, and prior to 1.7 [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) should be used in preference.

Comment: @Richard thank you! sorry for the late response, sitll new to stackoverflow.  Is there a way to turn on instant email alerts here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: none;` for the `#projectajax` in your css, in order to slideDown like this:

```
#projectajax{display: none; padding: 40px 0; }
```

Try it [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4SbXV/3/)

Comment: Thank you! still new to JQuery so I have trouble knowing when display: none; is needed.  Is there a rule behind this that makes it easier to understand when its needed?

Comment: In order to apply the `slideDown` animation on a div it must be invisible i. e. hidden i.e `display: none` it just change the display to block if you see the style of the page using firebug you will see after applying slideDown that the display property is changed.